# How to add the link to the product in twig?

Tags: drupal-8

I customized the template :

```
commerce-product.html.twig
```

I want to display a link to the product like this but using twig:

```
<a href="/my-product-link" title="my-product-title"></a>
```

How to add the link to the product in twig ?

Comment: I hope you have enabled debugging. You can customize from the suggestion template provided for the particular field.

Comment: @npcoder https://www.s1biose.com/service/relax-service-detente Here is the link of my page, I want to redo the block produced in the second sidebar.